# Pass a CSV as entry parameter in a REST API

Tags: c#, api, rest, csv

I have to develop a method in a REST API which will be called every hour. I have some methods with internal objects and I have not any problem. But this new method the entry parameter will be a CSV file. Which type have I declare for this parameter? I have tried some types but I can't find the properly type..

For example, I have another method like this:

```
[ActionName("RetrieveBookingList")]
[HttpPost]
public ListRS RetrieveBookingList(ListRQ rq)
{
    return MessageRetrieveBookingList.Execute(rq);
}
```

And someone can help me to how can send it (header, raw data (file attached?)) via POSTMAN or via SOAP UI in rest project to debug?

Many thanks.

Comment: if the whole file is going to be on the post body, you can always declare it as string, or you will need to create your own type and create your own model binder